# Can't import module: module can't be found in working file but works fine in another file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have the following file structure

```
Working Directory
  |
  |-- Package
  |     |-- __init__.py
  |     |-- FirstModule.py
  |     |-- SecondModule.py
  |     |-- TestingFile.ipynb
  |
  |-- WorkingFile.ipynb
```

#### `FirstModule.py`

```py
def func(n):
    return n+1
```

#### `SecondModule.py`

```py
import FirstModule

def func2(n):
    value = FirstModule.func(n)
    return (n, value)
```

When I import either module into `TestFile.ipynb` they work perfectly fine as shown here:

#### `TestingFile.ipnyb`

```
import FirstModule   # Works Fine
import SecondModule  # Works Fine
```

However, If I am in `WorkingFile.ipynb` and try to import `SecondModule` I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError`. More Specifically:

#### `WorkingFile.ipynb`

```py
from Package import SecondModule as sm
from Package import FirstModule as fm
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8a837a311e6c> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
----> 4 from Package import SecondModule as sm
      5 from Package import FirstModule as fm

~\Documents\Jupyter Notebooks\Working Directory\Package\SecondModule.py in <module>
     26 from datetime import datetime
     27 
---> 28 import FirstModule as fm
     29 
     30 # Constants

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FirstModule'
```

Could there be something that I am forgetting that is needed for modules to work together outside of the package that they are contained inside of?

Comment: first of when importing don't use `.py` second You have to start from working directory e.g. `from package.firstmodule import what_you_need` or `import package.firstmodule`

Comment: @Matiiss Sorry your first concern was a typo in the question. In my actual code it didn't have the `.py` I've corrected the typo in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the import statement in `SecondModule.py`.

I was able to reproduce the error using your example and when I change the import statement from

```
import FirstModule.py
```

to

```
from Package import FirstModule
```

It all works fine. You should not use the filename i.e. drop the **.py** from the import statement

You should use the package name explicitly when importing modules or alternatively use relative imports, i.e.

```
from . import FirstModule
```

or in case you only want specific objects/functions

```
from .FirstModule import some_function
```

Comment: Thank you! The `.py` was actually just a typo in my question; however changing `import FirstModule` in `SecondModule.py` to `from . import FirstModule` fixed my issue.